# Is there any way to get total number of documents being indexed

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

Is there anyway to find out ,how many documents are indexed out of total documents in couchbase bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the UI https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/monitor/monitor-intro.html

Bucket has total count listed. https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/monitor/ui-monitoring-statistics.html

Indexes has items indexed for each index. https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/monitor/monitoring-indexes.html